# Do you know any idiom/proverb for saying "that's great! Literally everybody got aware of our problem!"

Tags: idiom-requests

How do you sarcastically say "that's great! Literally everybody got aware of our problem!" if you want to use an idiom/proverb?

Comment: You could say "everyone knows" or "the world knows", which are both figures of speech, rather than idioms.

Comment: Or "Now everybody and his uncle knows..."

Answer (score 3):

In the UK You might say,

- ‘excellent, why not make an announcement in the Times while we’re at it?’
- ‘well done, that’s t[he cat thoroughly out of the bag](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/let+the+cat+out+of+the+bag)’
- If it’s in a more localised situation, where the people you really
  didn’t want to know are in the same room or same building and might
  overhear incautious discussion, you might say to the person who was
  being careless with their words, ‘would you like to say that a little
  louder? I’m not sure everyone in management/the office/the top floor
  quite heard you the first time.’

Comment: "Let the cat out if the bag" is used in American English as well.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Cheers, I didn't mean to suggest that it definitively wasn't, only that I could not speak for US usage.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not exactly what you're looking for, but "There's no such thing as bad publicity" might apply.